fault-tolerant syndrome extraction on a 2D square grid
Is there a known fault-tolerant syndrome extraction method for measuring an arbitrary multi-qubit Pauli operator on a 2D square grid of qubits?
I deliberately left out a space or time constraint. For simplicity, assume the Pauli operator acts on qubits located along one of the boundaries of the 2D square grid. See the figure below.
I consider a syndrome extraction circuit $\mathfrak{C}$ to be fault-tolerant if any $w$ circuit-level errors propagated to the end of $\mathfrak{C}$ results in an error with $X$ and $Z$ weight at most $w$. An example of a syndrome extraction circuit satisfying this definition is Shor style syndrome extraction, which uses auxiliary qubits encoded in  a cat state.


This is not a direct answer, but a very closely related task was studied in a paper by Shin Ho Choe and Robert Koenig (https://arxiv.org/abs/2402.13863). More directly, what notion of fault-tolerance are you thinking of? The probability of a single qubit error on any particular qubit is constant, so this task is impossible to accomplish with vanishing error unless your data qubits are already encoded (e.g. in a surface code)

I've updated my question to include the notion of fault-tolerance I'm considering. To give some more context, in this paper by Nicolas Delfosse, Michael E. Beverland, Maxime A. Tremblay (https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.14599) the authors construct 2D local syndrome extraction circuits for quantum LDPC codes.  I'm curious if there conclusions would change if they use fault-tolerant syndrome extraction circuits.

In that case, I think Shin Ho and Robert's work probably gives an affirmative answer to the asked question, but I don't want to misrepresent it. If the motivating question is "Does the DBT bound prohibit us from implementing a code family with a memory threshold in 2D that achieves better rate and logical error rate scaling over surface codes?" Then fortunately the answer is no (arxiv.org/abs/2303.04798) -- you can get very close to parameters of a good qLDPC code family at the cost of increased depth (which is what DBT proves must happen) –

It's worth noting that adversarial notions of fault-tolerance are frequently unsuitable for direct threshold arguments -- Only a very weak form is necessary and it can be shown to be insufficient (e.g. padding a syndrome extraction circuit with a super-constant number of identity gates preserves adversarial FT but kills any stochastic noise threshold). Code concatenation does allow the conversion from adversarial FT to a threshold in the stochastic setting, but otherwise translating between the two requires a good amount of care.
